# Convert dd-mm-yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a `varchar(200)` column called `Submit_Date` and I am trying to convert it to MM/DD/YYYY format. When I do that I get the following error:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Sample Data of the table is:

```
Submit_Date
-----------------------
27-09-2013 16:15:00 CST
30-09-2013 16:30:24 CST
27-09-2013 10:03:46 CST
```

I tried the following:

```
Select Convert(datetime,Submit_date,101) from dbo.Tickets
```

Comment: Why have you stored datetime data as varchar(200)?????

Comment: Its because of the characters "CST"

Comment: Why not use DATETIMEOFFSET, or store the time zone information separately?

Comment: the data comes in an excel sheet and we have a process to import the data. Basically it has some other characters also so basically its bad data so trying to convert into correct format

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've committed about 15 cardinal sins about date/time here. First, the quick answer:

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(200);

SELECT @x = '27-09-2013 16:15:00 CST'

SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10),CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(@x,10),105),101);
```

Next:

1. Why on earth are you storing date/time data in a `varchar(200)` column? You are aware that anyone can insert values like `'09-27-2013'` or `'465-32-207floob'` in there, right? If you need time zone information you can look at the [`DATETIMEOFFSET`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) data type (but note that it is not DST-aware).
2. Why are you storing a regional format like `dd-mm-yyyy`? If the first value were `07-11-2013` I'd have to guess if you meant July 11 or November 7. If you're not going to do it *right* and use a proper date/time data type, why use a string format that makes people guess? You are much better off with a format that is unambiguous, such as `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ`.
3. Similarly, why are you outputting a different regional format like `mm/dd/yyyy`? If you output `'05/06/2013'` are you 100% confident that everyone in your audience will know you meant May 6 and not June 5? Your output should be unambiguous as well. If you absolutely must format in some regional and ambiguous format, use the string formatting capabilities of your client. For example, C# has `.ToString()` and `.Format()` which are much more powerful and efficient in presenting dates with string formats that T-SQL will ever be.

Comment: Thanks you so much for the information Aaron i know that it's not a standard but thats how the users want it. I asked them to change it and they wont agree to it

Comment: @peter Your users should not be dictating how you store things in the DB.  Store it properly, and let the application format it.

Answer (score 1):

try the following SQL query to achieve the expected result:

```
SELECT convert(varchar, convert(date, '27-09-2013 16:15:00', 105), 101)
```